# Replacing all instances of string in one file with other

Tags: arrays, string, bash

I will get an input file which may contain a lot of bad words. I want to replace every occurrence of bad word with "beep"

Here is my input file:

**in.txt**

```
May I have your attention, please?
```

Bad words file:

**badwords.txt**

Contains bad words

My bash script to do what I intent to do:

**process.sh**

```
for badWord in ${badWords[@]}; do
    outtext={outtext/badWord/beep}
done
```

The output:

```
$ ./process.sh 
May I have your attention, please?
=====================================================
May I havbeep yobbeepbeeppbeep attbeepntion, plbeepabeepbeep?
```

Why this is not replacing bad words correctly?

Comment: Some of the lines in `cuss-words.txt` contain spaces, so they will be broken in the `for` loop if you don't enclose the `badWords` array at the `for` loop declaration in double quotes.

Comment: put a shebang on your script and paste it at https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the lines in `cuss-words.txt` contain spaces, so they will be broken at the `for` loop if you don't enclose the `badWords` array in double quotes.

Change this line:

```
for badWord in ${badWords[@]}; do
```

To this:

```
for badWord in "${badWords[@]}"; do
```